# Failed to download only package and dependencies on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I'm trying to download (download only, not install) some packages and it's dependencies so I can install them later offline. I was told to use the command `apt-get install --download-only [package]`.
This [works just fine on ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyiVu.png) but [fails on debian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjVoB.png) for some reason.

I'm using bind9 as an example but it's the same for every other package.

And I have tried [this](https://superuser.com/a/876735/947894), but the output is [also errors on debian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9hOe.png).

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @GAD3R [Here you go.](http://prntscr.com/kz5zz4)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by re-installing it and choosing a network mirror during the instalation.

Comment: Or simply edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file as the [documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list) say. (In your case the first URL is missing)